# Force mongoose to throw if find param is not an object

Tags: mongoose

Is there a way to force `mongoose` to throw an error if the `conditions` for a `find` query is not an `Object` but a `Number` or `String`?

Comment: Why do you need mongoose to do this? Could you not do this when validating the params?

Comment: I want to avoid typos like missing `{}` around the condition.

Answer (score 1):

Its better to check all condition and validate the request params. 
Forcing mongo db to throw error not good practice.
Mongo queries excepts object

```
let queryCondition = {};
queryCondition._id = "mongoDbId"
queryCondition.name = "anyName"

if(typeof(queryCondition) !== "object") return false

Model.find(queryCondition).lean();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use mongoose [pre](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html#notes) hook for this case

```
Model.pre('find', function () {
  if (typeof(this.getQuery()) !== "object") {
    next();
  } else {
    next(new Error('Your error message'))
  }
});
```